# Simple thread-safe Java hash map with weak values in Java or Google Guava?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, concurrency, guava

I want to keep a map of singleton objects based on their ID, just to ensure that everyone gets the same copy. The creation of these objects happens seldom, and I don't want or need the overhead of a concurrent map (which will internally keep essentially multiple maps in memory). But I do need the map to support weak keys, so that when nobody is using a particular instance the record will be dropped from the map.

So what choice do I have? Guava `MapMaker` and `CacheBuilder` create concurrent maps, which use a lot more memory than I need. I don't need "concurrency" --- I just need thread safety. Yes, I could set the concurrency level to `1`, but according to the API documentation this is is only a hint, and may be ignored altogether in the future.

I could use Java Collections to create a simple synchronized `HashMap` and use `putIfAbsent(...)`, but that doesn't give me the benefit of weak values. I could store weak references, but they wouldn't automatically be expunged on access of the map.

If I had a version of Java's `WeakHashMap` that supported weak values instead of weak keys, I could wrap it in a synchronized map and be done with it.

I believe that long ago Apache Commons Collections had a map builder that allowed the specification of weak values, but we're using Guava instead.

Any suggestions? And please, read the full question before jumping to throw in a suggestion I've already mentioned.

Comment: What part of the API documentation are you referring to with "only a hint"?  Besides -- at this point, it answers your question, it's only possibly less efficient than you need.

Comment: Clarification: How will you be determining that no one is using one of your map elements (are you requiring "obtain"/"release" calls using the ID ?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII, I used the phrase "using a particular instance" colloquially to mean "has a reference to a particular instance".

Comment: And do you have a reason for not using a well known cache implementation as what you are describing looks like a cache ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I would love to use a well-known cache implementation, if one meets the criteria I am looking for. If you know know of a well-known cache implementation that meets the criteria I mentioned, please name it. In fact... um, that was the question!

Comment: IMHO any good cache implementation returns a cached object for its id, and has strategies to evict an object that is no longer asked. And you can preload caches. What criteria would not be supported by EhCache or InfiniSpan ?

Comment: But @SergeBallesta I just want a tiny little map-like thing, preferably something already in Java or Guava. I'm just wanting to keep track of canonical instances for IDs.

Comment: Use Guava's caches for now, switch to something else if and only if the extra memory consumption is actually a problem in your application.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, the [MapMaker API docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#concurrencyLevel%28int%29) say, "Used as a hint for internal sizing." And in fact the [documentation for CacheBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#concurrencyLevel%28int%29) says, "Note that future implementations may abandon segment locking in favor of more advanced concurrency controls."

Comment: "More advanced concurrency controls" suggests that things will get better, not worse.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is a perfect example of misplaced optimization. You're saying you don't need concurrency and you don't want to pay the price for multiple map segments. But each such segment stores only a part of the entries, so the added overhead is no more than some hundreds bytes per segment, or rather less.

You're saying that the stored objects are singletons. This implies that you need only a single such map. Currently, Guava's cache creates the requested number of segments, i.e., one in your case (so the only memory overhead comes from the length one segment array (4 bytes) and some bookkeeping data (similar size). Assuming this should get much worse, and you get 64 segments with `concurrencyLevel(1)`, you'll lose maybe some kilobytes. Unless you're going to run your app on something like ZX Spectrum, it really shouldn't matter.

Maybe I've missed something, maybe you left out something. Feel free to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

create your own [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and use it in **`HashMap<key,weakObj>`** . Hope this might work.